# How to change the line ending in a Git repo dynamically

Tags: git

I have a Git repo that I checked out on Windows. When I installed Git, I chose "Use CRLF as local line ending" so the repo was cloned and checked out with all files having CRLF as line ending. This is giving me some problems since I have a lot of bash scripts and I use the Ubuntu bash in WSL. I have edited the global `.gitconfig` file to change the line ending to be consistent with the remote repo. But my files are still having the CRLF line ending. What is the best way to change all these back to their original line ending without deleting the repo directory and re-clone?

Comment: What about `git config --global core.autocrlf input`?

Comment: That is what I did. But the problem is the line ending remains CRLF for majority of my files because they have already been checked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But my files are still having the CRLF line ending.

If a file inside a commit inside the repository has CRLF line endings, that version of that file is stuck that way forever.  No part of any existing commit can ever be changed.

If a file inside a commit inside the repository has LF-only line endings, that version of that file is stuck that way forever.  However, you *can* can choose the ending you want to have Git place in your work-tree when you extract that file.

If you *already extracted the file*, Git has already done the conversion.  Git now thinks everything is fine, even if you just now changed the conversion setting.

Thus, if you change the conversion setting, you must force Git to re-extract the file.  The easiest way to do this consistently in all versions of Git is to *remove* the file from your work-tree, then run `git checkout -- path/to/file`.  Because the file is gone from the work-tree, Git will be forced to extract it again.  The updated EOL-conversion will be applied this time.

(Another way to do it is to alter the file, then run the same `git checkout`, or in Git 2.23 or later, to use `git restore`.  By telling Git that Git should discard your version of the file, and Git seeing that your version of the file is indeed "wrong" in that it doesn't match the index copy because you changed it, Git will be forced to re-extract the index copy.)

That may suffice for you case, or may not.  If it does not, read on.

#### What to know about Git's end-of-line conversions

I'm a firm believer in the "never use Windows at all so that you never need to have your version control system muck with line endings" philosophy myself, but there are a few things to know if you are in some other camp and *do* want Git to muck with line endings.  The most important of these is this: **What you store *in* Git, and what you use when you work with files you got *out* of Git, are not necessarily the same thing.**

To see how this works, remember that Git stores *commits* rather than directly storing files.  The *files inside those commits* come from Git's *index*, not from your work-tree.  The format of an index-copy of a file is the same as the internal format that Git uses for frozen-for-all-time commits: the data are pre-compressed.  So the copy of each file that's in the index is already significantly different from the copy you use in your work-tree, in that the one in your work-tree is not a Git blob object, and generally not zlib-compressed.

Git reads commits into the index before copying them out to your work-tree.  Running `git add` on a file compresses and blob-ifies the file in order to store it in Git's index.  *Right at this point of conversion*, while Git is compressing and Git-ifying a file (`git add`) or de-Git-ifying and decompressing a file (`git checkout-index` or equivalent), it's trivial for Git to insert *additional* conversion operations.

Git therefore does its thing at this point.  The things that Git can do—the *only* things built in directly—are that, on the way *out* of the index, Git can replace `\n`-only line endings with `\r\n` line endings, and on the way *into* the index, Git can replace `\r\n` line endings with `\n`-only line endings.

In other words, you can arrange for Git to *throw away* some carriage returns before *storing* a file, and to *add* some carriage returns when *extracting* a file.  If you do both of these, you get CRLF line endings in your work-tree and newline-only line endings in the commits.

You can, if you like, have Git do only *one* of these: in particular, with the `crlf=input` setting, you can tell Git: *do just one conversion, on the work-tree-to-index copy operation.*

If you choose to have Git do conversions when extracting files, the *only* conversion available here is *turn LF-only into CRLF*.  You cannot turn CRLF endings into LF-only endings.  If the in-Git *committed* file has CRLF endings, the in-work-tree extracted file will have CRLF endings.

Again, each of these conversions happens in just one direction:

- index → work-tree: optionally, replace `\n` with `\r\n`
- work-tree → index: optionally, replace `\r\n` with `\n`

What you choose with `core.autocrlf` or `.gitattributes` directives are:

- `text`, `-text`, and/or `core.autocrlf`: which files
- `eol=...` and/or `core.eol`: get which treatment(s)
- `crlf=input`: on which operation(s)

Once a file has been treated and converted—by copying it to or from the index—Git marks the index's copy as "matches the work-tree's copy" by grabbing key data from the OS: the file's size and other `lstat` system call values.  The precise details here vary because different OSes store different data with different granularity.

The easy way to force a new conversion is to remove one or the other copy of the file: `rm file` or `git rm --cached file` destroys the work-tree or index copy respectively, so now a `git checkout -- file` or `git add file` will make a new one.

When you run `git commit`, whatever bytes are in the *index* copy of the file go into the new commit that Git makes.  This new commit is now frozen for all time: the bytes that were in the index are now in the commit, forever (or for as long as the commit itself continues to exist).  Nothing and no one can change them.

#### Consequences of the above

What the above mean is that if you *do* plan to have your version control system (i.e., Git) muck about with line endings, the line endings you can—and thus probably should—*always* use for *every index copy*, and therefore every *committed* copy, of every text file are LF-only line endings.  These can always be converted to CRLF endings in a work-tree file, through an appropriate `.gitattributes` setting or `core.*` settings.  If you've done such a conversion, that work-tree file can be converted back to LF-only line endings on `git add` operations.

If you ever do *commit* a file with CRLF line endings, that commit is stuck that way for all time, and *extracting* that commit will give you a work-tree copy that has CRLF line endings, every time, because Git has no built in index → work-tree operation that will change this.  The only built in CRLF-to-LF operation that Git has only works in the other direction, index ← work-tree.

If you'd like to make a new and improved commit in which the committed copy of that file has LF-only line endings, you have these two options:

1. make sure your index ← work-tree settings do that, then force Git to add the file (e.g., change it in the work-tree or use `git rm --cached` on the index copy, and `git add` it); or
2. use any command that changes the work-tree copy to have LF-only line endings, e.g., run `dos2unix` on it or similar, then `git add` it.

The advantage to method 2 is that you can *see* the effect immediately (in your work-tree file) and it's hard to get it wrong.  The problem with method 1 is that you *can't* see it, and it's easy to get it totally wrong: e.g., you might accidentally use `git rm` instead of `git rm --cached`, which deletes both the index *and* work-tree copies.

Comment: Thanks. I have not had the chance to digest the whole yet but this is really helpful.