# Changing EOL from cr to crlf seems to be ignored by git

Tags: git, github, eol, gitattributes

I have a Github repo where I put some rather obscure files into; they have their own file ending (while being pretty much normal txt files) and are UTF-8-BOM encoded with `cr` eol.

Github doensn't like `cr` eols, so you have line breaks, but everything is still on *one* line which is understandably rather dumb for diffs.

So I made a `.gitattributes` file with `*.gdl text eol=crlf` – but git doesn't care.

Had anybody a similar case?
I'm on Windows, btw.

Comment: Changing the `.gitattributes` file will not affect other files *yet* (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60859454/1256452)), but if the lines are CR-only-terminated you'll need smudge and clean filters to turn them into LF-only or CRLF. Git's only built in option is CR-to-CRLF on the way out, and CRLF-to-LF on the way in (where "out" means "from frozen committed copy, to usable copy" and "in" means "from usable copy to frozen commit-able copy").

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought @torek, because it worked well with my other `lf` files.
Do you have a link to a ready to use clean&smudge filter for this task?

Comment: No, but if you have the Unix `sed`, sed can do it.

Comment: I'm on Windows, so it has to be something else.